# I want to insert a special character of SQL in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc

I want to translate this Access sql query to Java JDBC

`Select *
From books
Where Lcase(title) LIKE Lcase('*jdbc*') AND Lcase(title) LIKE Lcase('*programming*')`

I use a preparedStatement like this

```
String sql1="Select * From books Where Lcase(title) LIKE Lcase(%?%) AND Lcase(title) LIKE Lcase(%?%)";
PreparedStatement ps1=con.prepareStatement(sql1);
ps1.setString(1, "jdbc");
ps1.setString(2, "programming");
ResultSet rs1=ps1.executeQuery();
```

But I get a syntax error

Comment: can you try this Lcase('%?%'). add those quotes. kindly provide us a error log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to insert `%` into the value used by `Lcase`, you have two choices:

- Add `%`s in code, or
- Use concatenation in the query.

The first approach would look like this:

```
String sql1="Select * From books Where Lcase(title) LIKE Lcase(?) AND Lcase(title) LIKE Lcase(?)";
PreparedStatement ps1=con.prepareStatement(sql1);
ps1.setString(1, "%jdbc%");
ps1.setString(2, "%programming%");
```

The second approach would look like this:

```
String sql1="Select * From books Where Lcase(title) LIKE Lcase('%' & ? & '%') AND Lcase(title) LIKE Lcase('%' & ? & '%')";
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation, I´m noob on the site.